# buildTypes android studio error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm getting this error in my project gradle file:

> 'buildTypes' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure<
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType>)'

I'm currently using Android Studio 1.1.0, compileSdkVersion 22, buildToolsVersion 22.0.0, and targetSdkVersion 22. Using compileSdkVersion 21 seems to fix this problem. Any tips?

Edit:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.yyyy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you post the Gradle file in question. If I am reading it correctly, the error suggests that you have `buildTypes` inside of a build type itself (e.g., `buildTypes { debug { buildTypes { ... } } }`, which isn't going to work.

Comment: I just copied this into a scrap project. I don't have `buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"` installed, but using `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"`, I cannot reproduce the problem. Have you tried 22.0.1?

Comment: @CommonsWare I think Android Studio is crazy :D I removed the compileOptions because I saw that a new project is good, now I re-inserted them and now it works!!!

Comment: Could you answer your question and accept so this doesn't show up as an unanswered question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started a new fresh project and I saw that it works good, so I just copied the build.gradle file. Actually the only difference was the lack of compileOptions section. I removed the section, sync gradle, inserted the section again, sync gradle again and now it works!